# Probability of drawing balls out of a box

Tags: probability

I came across the following question today:

> "In drawing two balls from a box containing 6 red and 4 white balls without replacement, which of the following pairs will be independent?:
>
> (a) Red on 1st and red on 2nd draw
> (b) Red on 1st and white on 2nd draw

I approached this problem by writing down the sample space as {RW, RR, WW, WR} first.

Then, let $A$ be the event that red is drawn first and $B$ be the event that red is drawn second;
$A$=$({RW}, {RR}) and $B=$({RR}, {WR})

Which gives me $A∩B$={$RR$}

Therefore, I get
$P(A)=1/2$
$P(B)=1/2$ and
$P(A∩B)=1/4$

Which gives me $P(A)P(B)=P(A∩B)$, proving that A and B are independent events. However, clearly, this is nonsense! A and B are absolutely **not** independent events, since the occurrence of A affects the chances of occurrence of B. Where have I gone completely wrong in my reasoning?

Edit: My textbook has solved this problem correctly in the following way but I am not interested in the solution to this problem in particular; I want to know where I have made a grave mistake. Please correct me for if I don't understand my mistake, I will continue to commit the **same** mistake in the future as well. Much thanks in advance :) Regards.

[image: Textbook solution]

Comment: In order for your sample space approach to work, each result has to be *equally likely*. This is not the case in this problem.

Comment: Wait, if what are equally likely? If I were considering different events when throwing a pair of dice, then am I allowed to use the sample space approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in assuming that your four outcomes {RW, RR, WW, WR} are equally likely. They are not.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I will keep this in mind. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

$P(A)=\frac{6}{10}$ as initially there are $10$ balls and $6$ of them are red rather than $\frac12$.

You might like to recompute $P(B)$ and $P(A \cap B)$ too

Comment: Tomi has pointed out my mistake. Thanks! :)